# Convert byte array to file

Tags: c#, file, arrays

I have a file (D:/d.txt) that I'm converting to a byte array and then encrytping the array with RC4

```
 string filename="D:/d.txt"
    byte[] buff = null;
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, 
                                   FileMode.Open, 
                                   FileAccess.Read);
    BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
    long numBytes = new FileInfo(fileName).Length;
    buff = br.ReadBytes((int) numBytes);
    return buff;
```

but now I want to convert the array back to a file how can I do that

Comment: Just open a file and write it to the file.

Comment: You should really have `fs` in a `using` block, you are not closing the FileStream you opened to read the file. Also all of your code could be replaced with `return File.ReadAllBytes("D:/d.txt");`

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
  string filename = "D:/d.txt";
    byte[] buff = null;
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, 
                                   FileMode.Open, 
                                   FileAccess.Read);
    BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
    long numBytes = new FileInfo(filename).Length;
    buff = br.ReadBytes((int) numBytes);


File.WriteAllBytes("Foo.txt", buff);

//    or

File.WriteAllBytes("Foo.txt", buff.ToArray());
```

Documentation

> [`System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes` - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writeallbytes.aspx)